# (SSG-WSG) How do I connect to the Mock or Test API Gateway using the certificate method?

Tags: postman, x509certificate

Just using postman I can set up a certificate and connect to active subscriptions.  When I try and connect to the Mock API to test the connection for, getting course runs, for example, I am getting an error

> Error: error:0b000074:X.509 certificate routines:OPENSSL_internal:KEY_VALUES_MISMATCH

Is there a different way I am supposed to test certificate connections?

While it's not such a big deal with GET requests, this is going to be important for POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a certificate to call Mock APIs.

You can instead try to call it directly without the certificate as it will only display a mock response of the API.